# Coexisting Mqtt-Subscriber and UI crashes

Tags: java, javafx, mqtt

I’m more or less new in Java programming. I’m working on a program that receive a mqtt-message, that incomes nearly every second via a broker and have a UI. My problem is, if the mqtt-broker run, the UI won’t work.

Actually, I want to start the UI, that do some configuration stuff. There is one page in the UI that should do some analyzation tasks, for example capture the current status of the communication. Now I opened the mqtt broker as a counter in the UI -> the UI stage disappears and only the broker runs.

The goal should be, that first the UI runs… In the next step only one message is captured and added to the counter, the UI waits and stay opened (visible) while this process. After this process the broker have a break, and the UI can run again and maybe repeats the whole process again and again.

Sorry for this confusing description, but maybe someone have a solution for my problem.. Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that you're preforming task that takes too long time on the UI thread, as such the UI stops working, if you want to preform a task that takes too long time in the UI, you need to create a new thread, either a normal one with the Thread class, or a UI thread with the Platform.runLater() method to handle the time consuming task.

Comment: Just as a note if you create a normal thread you will not be able to change the UI from it, you will need to run a sub UI thread inside to update the UI.

Comment: Ah, ok.. Is it complicated to do that? So, as I write above, I'm no totally beginner, but also no crack on that point.. Can you maybe please give a simple example?

Comment: It's not that complicated to be honest, if you have any andriod/mobile experience you will have had to deal with this kind of problem, i will write some simple code, to help you understand.

Comment: Nice! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example

```
public void someLongTask(){
    new Thread(()->{
        //code for task here
        Platform.runLater(()->{
            //code to update UI here
        });
    }).start()
}
```

as a note i used Lambda expressions to reduce amount of code

Comment: Ok, great! Thank you! I guess I got it!

Answer (score 0):

Short update ...

More or less the solution of Bara 'Hashesh work fine, now the UI and the mqtt-broker coexisting.

Now the problem is that the new openned thread is an "endless" thread, cause the mqtt message is incomming again and again until you stop it manuelly. Is there a way to interupt the new started process.. 
I had read about a method `mythread.interupt` but can't find a way to combine it with the current method.

Comment: I assume you have some sort of while(true) in the thread right?  You can replace it with a while(running), where running is a boolean value.  Once you set this to false the thread will stop.

Answer (score 0):

Basically this is the public script by IBM I use for the communication. I dumped the imports and some comments they are actually not important for the problem. To anwser your question Martin, there is actually no while contained...

public class MqttCommunicationClassv1 implements MqttCallback {

```
/**
 * The main entry point of the sample.
 *
 * This method handles parsing of the arguments specified on the command-line
 * before performing the specified action.
 * mqtt_action = publish || subscribe
 */
public static void mqtt_start(String mqtt_action)
{
    // Default settings:
    boolean quietMode = false;
    String action =  mqtt_action;
    String topic = "";
    String message = "Message from client !!!";
    int qos = 2;
    String broker = "192.168.100.1";
    int port = 1883;
    String clientId = null;
    String subTopic = "RPI-Measurement";
    String pubTopic = "RPI-Measurement";
    boolean cleanSession = true; // Non durable subscriptions
    boolean ssl = false;
    String password = null;
    String userName = null;
    // Parse the arguments -

    // Validate the provided arguments
    if (!action.equals("publish") && !action.equals("subscribe")) {
        System.out.println("Invalid action: " + action);
        printHelp();
        return;
    }
    if (qos < 0 || qos > 2) {
        System.out.println("Invalid QoS: " + qos);
        printHelp();
        return;
    }
    if (topic.equals("")) {
        // Set the default topic according to the specified action
        if (action.equals("publish")) {
            topic = pubTopic;
        } else {
            topic = subTopic;
        }
    }

    String protocol = "tcp://";

    if (ssl) {
        protocol = "ssl://";
    }

    String url = protocol + broker + ":" + port;

    if (clientId == null || clientId.equals("")) {
        clientId = "SampleJavaV3_" + action;
    }

    // With a valid set of arguments, the real work of
    // driving the client API can begin
    try {
        // Create an instance of this class
        MqttCommunicationClassv1 sampleClient = new MqttCommunicationClassv1(url, clientId, cleanSession, quietMode,
                userName, password);

        // Perform the requested action
        if (action.equals("publish")) {
            sampleClient.publish(topic, qos, message.getBytes());
        } else if (action.equals("subscribe")) {
            sampleClient.subscribe(topic, qos);
        }
    } catch (MqttException me) {
        // Display full details of any exception that occurs
        System.out.println("reason " + me.getReasonCode());
        System.out.println("msg " + me.getMessage());
        System.out.println("loc " + me.getLocalizedMessage());
        System.out.println("cause " + me.getCause());
        System.out.println("excep " + me);
        me.printStackTrace();
    }
// Private instance variables
private MqttClient client;
private String brokerUrl;
private boolean quietMode;
private MqttConnectOptions conOpt;
private boolean clean;
private String password;
private String userName;

/**
 * Constructs an instance of the sample client wrapper
 * 
 * @param brokerUrl    the url of the server to connect to
 * @param clientId     the client id to connect with
 * @param cleanSession clear state at end of connection or not (durable or
 *                     non-durable subscriptions)
 * @param quietMode    whether debug should be printed to standard out
 * @param userName     the username to connect with
 * @param password     the password for the user
 * @throws MqttException
 */
public MqttCommunicationClassv1(String brokerUrl, String clientId, boolean cleanSession, boolean quietMode,
        String userName, String password) throws MqttException {
    this.brokerUrl = brokerUrl;
    this.quietMode = quietMode;
    this.clean = cleanSession;
    this.password = password;
    this.userName = userName;
    // This sample stores in a temporary directory... where messages temporarily
    // stored until the message has been delivered to the server.
    // ..a real application ought to store them somewhere
    // where they are not likely to get deleted or tampered with
    String tmpDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
    MqttDefaultFilePersistence dataStore = new MqttDefaultFilePersistence(tmpDir);

    try {
        // Construct the connection options object that contains connection parameters
        // such as cleanSession and LWT
        conOpt = new MqttConnectOptions();
        conOpt.setCleanSession(clean);
        if (password != null) {
            conOpt.setPassword(this.password.toCharArray());
        }
        if (userName != null) {
            conOpt.setUserName(this.userName);
        }

        // Construct an MQTT blocking mode client
        client = new MqttClient(this.brokerUrl, clientId, dataStore);

        // Set this wrapper as the callback handler
        client.setCallback(this);

    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log("Unable to set up client: " + e.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}

/**
 * Publish / send a message to an MQTT server
 * 
 * @param topicName the name of the topic to publish to
 * @param qos       the quality of service to delivery the message at (0,1,2)
 * @param payload   the set of bytes to send to the MQTT server
 * @throws MqttException
 */
public void publish(String topicName, int qos, byte[] payload) throws MqttException {

    // Connect to the MQTT server
    log("Connecting to " + brokerUrl + " with client ID " + client.getClientId());
    client.connect(conOpt);
    log("Connected");

    String time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
    log("Publishing at: " + time + " to topic \"" + topicName + "\" qos " + qos);

    // Create and configure a message
    MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(payload);
    message.setQos(qos);

    // Send the message to the server, control is not returned until
    // it has been delivered to the server meeting the specified
    // quality of service.
    client.publish(topicName, message);

    // Disconnect the client
    client.disconnect();
    log("Disconnected");
}

/**
 * Subscribe to a topic on an MQTT server Once subscribed this method waits for
 * the messages to arrive from the server that match the subscription. It
 * continues listening for messages until the enter key is pressed.
 * 
 * @param topicName to subscribe to (can be wild carded)
 * @param qos       the maximum quality of service to receive messages at for
 *                  this subscription
 * @throws MqttException
 */
public void subscribe(String topicName, int qos) throws MqttException {

    // Connect to the MQTT server
    client.connect(conOpt);
    log("Connected to " + brokerUrl + " with client ID " + client.getClientId());

    // Subscribe to the requested topic
    // The QoS specified is the maximum level that messages will be sent to the
    // client at.
    // For instance if QoS 1 is specified, any messages originally published at QoS
    // 2 will
    // be downgraded to 1 when delivering to the client but messages published at 1
    // and 0
    // will be received at the same level they were published at.
    log("Subscribing to topic \"" + topicName + "\" qos " + qos);
    client.subscribe(topicName, qos);

    // Continue waiting for messages until the Enter is pressed
    log("Press <Enter> to exit");
    try {
        System.in.read();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // If we can't read we'll just exit
    }

    // Disconnect the client from the server
    client.disconnect();
    log("Disconnected");
}

/**
 * Utility method to handle logging. If 'quietMode' is set, this method does
 * nothing
 * 
 * @param message the message to log
 */
private void log(String message) {
    if (!quietMode) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

/****************************************************************/
/* Methods to implement the MqttCallback interface */
/****************************************************************/

/**
 * @see MqttCallback#connectionLost(Throwable)
 */
public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
    // Called when the connection to the server has been lost.
    // An application may choose to implement reconnection
    // logic at this point. This sample simply exits.
    log("Connection to " + brokerUrl + " lost!" + cause);
    System.exit(1);
}

/**
 * @see MqttCallback#deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken)
 */
public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
    // Called when a message has been delivered to the
    // server. The token passed in here is the same one
    // that was passed to or returned from the original call to publish.
    // This allows applications to perform asynchronous
    // delivery without blocking until delivery completes.
    //
    // This sample demonstrates asynchronous deliver and
    // uses the token.waitForCompletion() call in the main thread which
    // blocks until the delivery has completed.
    // Additionally the deliveryComplete method will be called if
    // the callback is set on the client
    //
    // If the connection to the server breaks before delivery has completed
    // delivery of a message will complete after the client has re-connected.
    // The getPendingTokens method will provide tokens for any messages
    // that are still to be delivered.
}

/**
 * @return 
 * @see MqttCallback#messageArrived(String, MqttMessage)
 */
public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws MqttException {

    // Called when a message arrives from the server that matches any
    // subscription made by the client
    String time = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString();
    System.out.println("Time:\t" + time + "  Message:\t" + new String(message.getPayload()));
    mqttMssg = new String(message.getPayload());
    System.out.println("Instance 1");


}

/****************************************************************/
/* End of MqttCallback methods */
/****************************************************************/

static void printHelp() {
    System.out.println("Syntax:\n\n" + "    Sample [-h] [-a publish|subscribe] [-t <topic>] [-m <message text>]\n"
            + "            [-s 0|1|2] -b <hostname|IP address>] [-p <brokerport>] [-i <clientID>]\n\n"
            + "    -h  Print this help text and quit\n" + "    -q  Quiet mode (default is false)\n"
            + "    -a  Perform the relevant action (default is publish)\n"
            + "    -t  Publish/subscribe to <topic> instead of the default\n"
            + "            (publish: \"Sample/Java/v3\", subscribe: \"Sample/#\")\n"
            + "    -m  Use <message text> instead of the default\n"
            + "            (\"Message from MQTTv3 Java client\")\n"
            + "    -s  Use this QoS instead of the default (2)\n"
            + "    -b  Use this name/IP address instead of the default (m2m.eclipse.org)\n"
            + "    -p  Use this port instead of the default (1883)\n\n"
            + "    -i  Use this client ID instead of SampleJavaV3_<action>\n"
            + "    -c  Connect to the server with a clean session (default is false)\n"
            + "     \n\n Security Options \n" + "     -u Username \n" + "     -z Password \n"
            + "     \n\n SSL Options \n" + "    -v  SSL enabled; true - (default is false) "
            + "    -k  Use this JKS format key store to verify the client\n"
            + "    -w  Passpharse to verify certificates in the keys store\n"
            + "    -r  Use this JKS format keystore to verify the server\n"
            + " If javax.net.ssl properties have been set only the -v flag needs to be set\n"
            + "Delimit strings containing spaces with \"\"\n\n"
            + "Publishers transmit a single message then disconnect from the server.\n"
            + "Subscribers remain connected to the server and receive appropriate\n"
            + "messages until <enter> is pressed.\n\n");
}
```

}